# Alert Box that displays written text in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown list. When someone clicks the option "Other" in the dropdown list, a blank line appears to allow someone to write his or her own request. I want to create an alert box which displays what someone wrote in the blank line in big, bold letter. How do I do this?

Here's my code:

```
<form action="">
    <select name="requests" onchange ="checkIfOther();" id="dropDown1">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="good morning sir">Good Morning Sir</option>
    <option value="temperature">The current temperature is _____ centigrade.</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>    
</select>
</form>

 </p>
 <button onclick="myFunction()" value>Submit</button>

     <div id="other" style="display:none">  
         <br><br><label>Optional Request: </label><input type="text" id="otherText"/>

         </div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
   function checkIfOther(){
         a = document.getElementById("dropDown1");        
         if(a.value == "other")           
             document.getElementById("other").setAttribute("style","display:inline");
        else
             document.getElementById("other").setAttribute("style","display:none");
         }
</script>

<script>
   function myFunction(){
       var x=document.getElementById("dropDown1");
       alert("You have chosen: " + x.options[x.selectedIndex].text);
       if(x.value == "other"){
           b=document.getElementById("other"); 
               alert("You have chosen: " + b.text); //what do I do?
               }   
           }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by ' pop-up window' ? browser window ? or floating div ? or alert box ? What is 'this request' ? You mean what the user entered as 'other' ?

Comment: Sounds like a floating div

Comment: By pop-up window I mean an alert box. Request means, if you type something in the Other textbox and click the submit button, an alert box should pop up saying "You have chosen: _____." (In the underdash is whatever you typed in the Other section.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Jquery, Here is code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function myFunction(){
    alert('You have chosen: '+$("#otherText").val());
}

function checkIfOther()
{
    $("#otherText").val('');
    ($("#dropDown1").val() == 'other') ?  $("#other").show() :  $("#other").hide();
}

</script>
```

let me know is this helpful?.

Answer (score 0):

But I did something like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mySubmit(){
        var x=document.getElementById("dropDown1");
        if(x.value == "other"){
            alert("You have chosen: " + otherText.value); 
        }
        else {  
            alert("You have chosen: " + x.options[x.selectedIndex].text);
        }
    }   
</script>
```